# Flutter Camera start record lag

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, android-camera, flutter-dependencies

Perhaps this is due to my own code, I'm fairly new to flutter.
I'm using the built in camera library to record video. The problem being that there is a notable lag between hitting record and the video starting to record / updating the live preview.

This lag is probably 1-3 seconds.

Our code is very simple:

```
void _cameraRecordPress() async {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) return;
    if (controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      controller.stopVideoRecording();
      setState(() {
        recordState = false;
      });
      String result = await Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => PostRecordPage(
                    recording: recording,
                  )));
      Navigator.pop(context, result);
      return;
    }

    final String currentTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    final String filePath = '$videoDirectory/$currentTime.mp4';
    controller.startVideoRecording(filePath);
    recording.path = File(filePath);
    setState(() {
      recordState = true;
    });
  }
```

We call controller.prepareForVideoRecording(); prior to this call.
This is all in the async event for the button. Is there some way to improve performance here? I can't really see a way of moving this record to the background or anything. Maybe a more complex flutter trick?

Comment: How long before you call `_cameraRecordPress` do you call `controller.prepareForVideoRecording`? And what OS/version is your mobile device?

Comment: We call prepare for record on page load. This is a pixel 3 with the latest android.

Comment: @nullnull did you found a solution?

Comment: I would try to put recording.path = File(filePath); before the start of the video. Sometimes it helps to just print some text between every statement. Pls try it out!

Comment: To exclude filesystem delays - try write to a memory mapped file.  `final String filePath = '$videoDirectory/$currentTime.mp4';`